# SliceIndex trait bound unsatisfied error when trying to index into a vector in Rust

Tags: vector, indexing, rust

I have a struct:

```
pub struct SomeCollection<'a> {
    items: Vec<&'a SomeValue>,
    name_mapping: HashMap<&'a str, usize>,
    index_mapping: HashMap<&'a str, usize>
}

impl<'a> Index for SomeCollection<'a> {
    type Output = Option<&'a SomeValue>;

    fn index(&self, value_name: &str) -> &Self::Output {
        match self.name_mapping.get(value_name) {
            Some(index) => &self.items.get(index),
            None => match self.index_mapping.get(value_name) {
                Some(index) => &self.items.get(index),
                None => &None
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try compiling this code I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&usize: std::slice::SliceIndex<[&SomeValue]>` is not satisfied
  --> src\some_collection.rs:49:48
   |
49 |                 Some(index) => &self.items.get(index),
   |                                            ^^^ slice indices are of 
type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[&SomeValue]>` is not implemented for `&usize`
```

Rust seems to be telling me that I can't index into a vector with `index`, which is a `usize`. I'm not sure why I need to implement this trait as it should be implemented for the default vector already. Can anyone enlighten me as to the real reason I'm getting this error? There may be other errors in this code that haven't surfaced yet so please bear that in mind when answering.

Comment: Please post a code which reproduces your error. I believe your full code should be like this : [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae487d75067205ea6a8672dcc8eacc3a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the compiler error is hard to understand, but at least it is accurate.  It tells you, that `index` is a reference `&usize` however a `Vec` can only be indexed with the value `usize`.  So all you have to do is dereference `index`.

Moreover, usually indexing `panic`s if the key/index could not be found.  (That's why the standard library offers the `Vec::get`, and `HashMap::get` as separate methods alongside indexing, which do not `panic` but return `None` if the given key/index not in the collection.)

```rust
impl<'a> Index<&str> for SomeCollection<'a> {
    type Output = &'a SomeValue;

    fn index(&self, value_name: &str) -> &Self::Output {
        match self.name_mapping.get(value_name) {
            Some(index) => &self.items[*index],
            None => match self.index_mapping.get(value_name) {
                Some(index) => &self.items[*index],
                None => panic!("Missing key: {:?}", value_name),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Rust seems to be telling me that I can't index into a vector with `index`, which is a `usize`.

No, the compiler is telling you that you can't index a vector with an `&usize`.

```
the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[&SomeValue]>` is not implemented for `&usize`
```

Simply using `*index` instead will fix this particular problem. However, your code has other problems as well:

- The `Index` trait needs a type parameter, e.g. `&str` in this case.
- The `index()` method can generally only return a reference to data stored in the data structure you are indexing. Your code creates a temporary `Option`, which is not stored in the original data, and then tries to return a reference to that. If this is what you want to do, you need to define your own method (or trait) that returns the `Option` by value instead.